# Flutter: Download file from server, edit in third party app, re-upload when edited

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Not even sure if this is possible at all, but here's what I need to do (OK means I am able to do this)...

1. Download file using a REST service, save to device (iOS, Android) - OK, using Dio
2. Open file in default application (for example Word or similar) - OK, using open_file
3. The user alters the file some way - can't get this one to work, file is read-only
4. Returning to my App, I need to re-upload the file if it has been altered - should be easy when I solve 3 and it is possible to determine if the file has been updated since it was downloaded (checking file write date or similar)

Now, the reason the file is read-only I assume is because it is downloaded to my apps storage. Is it possible to downlad a file to a location where the third-party app has write access to said file? Is this stuff even possible on a mobile device? I am writing both the client app and the REST server.

An alternative, I guess, could be to have my server upload the file to Google Drive, OneDrive or similar and have the third party app open the file from there... The user is authenticated, so I guess I could pick up the authentication token (JWT) and use this communicating with OneDrive or similar.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your intent to open a default application for the file.

Comment: `the reason the file is read-only I assume is because it is downloaded to my apps storage`. No. Moreover you will use a FileProvider to serve your file. So the third party app will read from en write to the file provider. It has no idea of a location.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps
Seems there are no plugins for Flutter that'll do that. Thanks for the tip though. I had hoped I would be able to do this without becoming an Android and iOS "expert" :-)

Comment: Of course you can serve a file in Flutter using a FileProvider. Would be bad if you could not do this standard operation. But... i do not program with Flutter..